# Cordova IOS platform, disable camera from file input options

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cordova

I've file input in my app. When trying to upload a file, on IOS, it gives options to capture a photo using the camera. How can I disable the camera option?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fcgF.png)

Comment: can you share code?

Comment: <label class="btn btn-primary">
    {{$t('Upload')}}
<input type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" capture="filesystem" id="profileImageInput" class="uploadFile img" value="Upload Photo">
</label>